# Хочу научиться делать сайты

Tags: веб-сайт

Xочу научиться самостоятельно создавать сайты. Подскажите какие языки лучше, какие книги почитать и какие связки дадут лучший результат в изучении?

Comment: Скорее всего, ответы на этот вопрос будут основаны на мнениях, а не на фактах и цитатах. Необходимо переформулировать его так, чтобы на него можно было дать объективный ответ.

Comment: Вместо заминусовывания и закрытия вопроса, можно было помочь составить правильную формулировку вопроса. Новичкам сложно войти в это русло в связи с непониманием.

Comment: Дополните, пожалуйста, Ваш вопрос. Хорошо было бы указать, что Вам важно в сайте, например: быстродействие, кроссплатформенность, скорость разработки, сложность входа, асинхронность, экосистема и т. д. Потому что писать серверную часть можно практически на чём угодно.

Comment: https://www.playframework.com/ удобный и гибкий фреймворк на джава и скала. Вообще, советую использовать похожие решения, потому как многие (но не все) проблемы (в том числе и проблемы безопасности) закрываются автоматически.

Answer (score 1):

## Бэкенд, фронтенд, серверы и т.д.

- #### [Python](https://www.python.org/):

  1. [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)
  2. [Flask](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flask_(%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA))
- #### [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/intro-whatis.php):

  1. [Laravel](https://laravel.com/)
  2. [Symfony](https://symfony.com/)
  3. [etc.](https://www.hostinger.ru/rukovodstva/8-luchshih-php-framework-dla-web-razrabotchikov/#1-Laravel)
- #### [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/ru/)

  1. Ruby On Rails

---

## Сами страницы

- #### HTML

  [1](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/HTML/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B2_HTML), [2](http://htmlbook.ru/html) etc.
- #### [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/CSS_basics#:%7E:text=CSS%20(Cascading%20Style%20Sheets)%20%E2%80%94,%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1%2D%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B.)
- #### [Javascript](https://learn.javascript.ru/)